# Python OpenCV2 - how to get number and time of frame from video?

Tags: python, opencv, video

I am processing a video with OpenCV in Python. I would like to make some automated notes according findings in video. I know I can count frames to get number of frame, but is there some simple way how to get time where the frame stands in this video (for people who will watch the video in media players)?

I am accessing the frames as follows:

```
video = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
ret, self.image = video.read()
```

Comment: Read out fps (which is stored in the container) and do the calculation manually.

Comment: @sascha Thanks, that sounds doable.

Comment: [`VideoCapture.get`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#aeb1644641842e6b104f244f049648f94): `CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC` -- Current position of the video file in milliseconds or video capture timestamp.